# Do I have to docker rebuild an image to deploy code changes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Should I run this command to make the server recognize my code changes?

`docker-compose build && docker-compose push`

I pulled my code changes from git to the server but the server isn't reflecting my code changes.

Comment: How look like your Dockerfile? are you using ADD ./code to dockerfile?

Comment: Yes I have `ADD . /app_name` in the Dockerfile.